# In Ollama, how can I get a report of memory usage?

Tags: memory, monitoring, ollama

I'm interested in watching the memory usage of a model being run under ollama.

How can I see the memory usage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know a way directly in Ollama, but you could get a rough estimate for this information from your graphics card, e.g. `nvidia-smi`:

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                            |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                            GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                             Usage      |
|=======================================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      1345      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                          378MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      2490      G   cinnamon                                     57MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      3663      G   ...ures=SpareRendererForSitePerProcess       25MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A    121270      G   /usr/lib/firefox/firefox                    160MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A    131205      C   ...p/gguf/build/cuda/bin/ollama-runner     4868MiB |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```